# Codeigniter Change field name on error reporting?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Well here is a example error Codeigniter will shoot out at the user if they don't type in their email.

> email: The Email field is required.

Now the "email" part specifically. How can I change it to whatever I like? It seems its using the inputs name/id.

Example of how I setup form validation for email.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]');
```

So maybe a better example .. say I wanted to change it from saying "email" to "The Email"

Thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use set_message function in form_validation library.For example;

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('email', '%s is entered email adress, it's wrong!');
```

CodeIgniter's user-guide is very easy and interactive.You should check the documentation for these type of basic questions.

[CodeIgniter user-guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/)

Comment: If I do it this way how does CI know which form it is setting the message for?

Comment: The CodeIgniter know it from first parameter of function that is a `email`.This parameter points to the inputs name.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

If you want to alter the message use set_message:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Your custom message here');
```

Using a Callback is a better way to do it:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'check_user_name');


public function username_check($str)
    {
        if (strlen($str)<0)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_user_name', 'The %s field is empty"');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```